# Importing ASCII files as cell array instead of structure

Tags: matlab, import, ascii

I am loading ASCII data into Matlab and I would prefer them to be stored as a cell array instead of structures, to make subsequent analyses more straightforward.

When I'm using the `uiimport` function it lets me import the data as a cell array, but I would like to import a large number of data without a graphical interface. Now, I've been trying to use the `importdata` function as:

```
data=importdata(filename,'\t',15);
```

which works perfectly, except for the fact that it saves the data as a struct. Is there any other way to do this, or would it be the fastest for me to just make a cell of the struct?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If your data is formatted then you probably want to check `textscan`. Can you add an example (a small bit) of your data file?

Comment: Since it seems to work with the `uiimport` GUI, why don't you simply check the "Generate MATLAB code` checkbox and let matlab generate the code for you?

Comment: why not using `struct2cell` to convert the structure into a cell? Otherwise use `textscan`.

Comment: @H.Muster I tried generating the code, but that also uses `importdata` and unfortunately doesn't seem to give me any insight in how the data output file is generated

Comment: @H.Muster I tried using generating code with this once, but it was some pita from my point of view. well, of course the reason was, that I didn't and still dont know how to use it effectivly :o

Comment: Do you mean the generated code behaves unexpectedly, or that you struggle to adapt it?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin The generated code is an `importdata` with the same inputparameters as I had figured out on my own, but somehow if I generate the code with `uiimport` it outputs the data as a cell whereas when i program it myself with `importdata` it outputs as a structured cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't have a very pretty solution, but it works. So I've went for using `importdata` after all, using a for loop creating a cell containing a structured array for each subject and trial,

```
    ntrials=4; %# of trials per subject
    datanamelist=['subjectA'; 'subjectB'; 'etc' ];
    for i=1:size(datanamelist,1)
        for j=1:ntrials;
        filename=sprintf('%s%g.txt',datanamelist(i,:),j);
        PDdata{i,j}=importdata(filename,'\t',15); %first 15 lines are headers
        end
    end
```

I am now able to extract the data from each particular array, accessing it as `PDdata{subject,ntrials}.data`

And as such create a 4D matrix containing all data by (looping over subjects i and trials j)

```
dataMatrix(:,:,i,j)=PDdata{i,j}.data
```

Prettier solutions are still welcome